# Collect associated data from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array in PHP:

```
array(29) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "Kråksjö 111 1987-01-16"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "Kråksjö 1953-06-16"
  [2]=>
  string(25) "Skir ÄNGARNA 1 1967-07-12"
  [3]=>
  string(18) "Kråksjö 1967-07-12"
  [4]=>
  string(22) "Kråksjö 383 1928-10-03"
  [5]=>
  string(29) "Kråksjö JOHANSTORP 1928-10-03"
  [6]=>
  string(22) "Kråksjö 119 1982-11-06"
  [7]=>
  string(22) "Kråksjö 119 1957-05-16"
  [8]=>
  string(18) "Kråksjö 1926-08-21"
  [9]=>
  string(28) "Kråksjö LYCKEBORG 1926-08-21"
  [10]=>
  string(30) "Västra Vallgatan 27 1962-12-17"
  [11]=>
  string(18) "Kråksjö 1962-12-17"
  [12]=>
  string(22) "Kråksjö 111 1986-12-08"
  [13]=>
  string(22) "Kråksjö 119 1949-02-03"
  [14]=>
  string(22) "Kråksjö 135 1947-09-04"
  [15]=>
  string(22) "Kråksjö 135 1951-06-29"
  [16]=>
  string(18) "Kråksjö 1945-09-17"
  [17]=>
  string(23) "Kråksjö HAGA 1945-09-17"
  [18]=>
  string(22) "Kråksjö 135 1970-01-01"
  [19]=>
  string(22) "Kråksjö 135 1983-07-03"
  [20]=>
  string(22) "Kråksjö 383 1970-01-01"
  [21]=>
  string(18) "Kråksjö 1969-07-10"
  [22]=>
  string(24) "Nickalycke 19 1969-07-10"
  [23]=>
  string(20) "Hästebäck 1960-03-13"
  [24]=>
  string(21) "Kråksjö 51 1960-03-13"
  [25]=>
  string(21) "Kråksjö 51 1968-11-13"
  [26]=>
  string(18) "Kråksjö 1938-09-03"
  [27]=>
  string(18) "Kråksjö 1964-10-22"
  [28]=>
  string(18) "Kråksjö 1953-06-16"
}
```

The thing I want to do is calculate how many persons it is in every household. As you can see, Kråksjö 119 appears 3times, which means it is 3persons who have that address. I also want to calculate the age intervall of the persons in the household: 10-30years, 30-50years and 50-70 years.

This data should be represented in a table like this:

```
Address         Persons in house        10-30years          30-50years          50-70years
Kråksjö 119         3                       1                   1                   1
Kråksjö 112         2                       0                   0                   2
```

As you can see, the address should only be represented once in the table.

I have tried like this with PHP:

```
foreach($adress as $key => $value)
{
    $newArray[$key]['adress'] = substr($value, 0, -10); //Dela upp adressen //Get the address
    $newArray[$key]['dob'] = substr($value, -10);       //Dela upp personnummer //Get the date of birth
}

$printed_vals = array();
foreach($newArray as $arr)
{
    if(!in_array($arr['adress'], $printed_vals)) {
        $printed_vals[] = $arr['adress'];               //Unique addresses
    }
}
```

I don't know how to coming the date of birth interval with the unique addresses

Comment: You have trouble determining the age?

Comment: @Jack: No, I have trouble to represent the age for each address as shown in my question.

Comment: Well, you have to use the address as the key of your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new array you are making. Use adress as your key. and add the dobs as its elements.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($adress as $key => $value)
{
    $adress = substr($value, 0, -10);
    $dob = substr($value, -10);

    if(!isset($newArray[$adress])) {
         $newArray[$adress] = array();
    }

    $newArray[$adress][] = $dob;

}
```

#### update to below comments

```
<?php

$adress = array("Kråksjö 111 1987-01-16","Kråksjö 1953-06-16","Skir ÄNGARNA 1 1967-07-12","Kråksjö 1967-07-12","Kråksjö 383 1928-10-03"
,"Kråksjö JOHANSTORP 1928-10-03","Kråksjö 119 1982-11-06","Kråksjö 119 1957-05-16","Kråksjö 1926-08-21","Kråksjö LYCKEBORG 1926-08-21",
"Västra Vallgatan 27 1962-12-17","Kråksjö 1962-12-17","Kråksjö 111 1986-12-08","Kråksjö 119 1949-02-03","Kråksjö 135 1947-09-04",
"Kråksjö 135 1951-06-29","Kråksjö 1945-09-17","Kråksjö HAGA 1945-09-17","Kråksjö 135 1970-01-01","Kråksjö 135 1983-07-03"
,"Kråksjö 383 1970-01-01");

$newArray = array();
foreach($adress as $key => $value)
{
    $adress = substr($value, 0, -10);
    $dob = substr($value, -10);

    if(!isset($newArray[$adress])) {
         $newArray[$adress] = array();
    }

    $newArray[$adress][] = $dob;

}

echo "<table><tr><td>Address</td><td>Persons</td><td>10-30</td><td>30-50</td><td>50-70</td></tr>";
foreach ($newArray as $address => $val) {

    echo "<tr><td>".$address."</td><td>".count($val)."</td><td>".somefunction($val,10,30)."</td><td>".somefunction($val,30,50)."</td><td>".somefunction($val,50,70)."</td></tr>";

}
echo "<table>";

function somefunction($vals,$start,$end) {

    $count = 0;

    foreach($vals as $val) {

        $age = floor(abs(time() - strtotime($val))/(365*60*60*24));
        if( $age > $start && $age < $end)
            $count++;

    }

    return $count;

}


?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I print out the adress and it's date of birth in an foreach?

Comment: i have put the sample code add logic for looping array and counting the age in `somefunction`

Comment: I can't make it work. I have tried like this: http://pastebin.com/mpypYcQV can u help me?

Comment: refer to the latest code i posted. i have defined `somefunction` with the logic. copy and paste the code its working in my local.

Comment: @user500468 : cant u accept the answer if its solving your issue. I will look into it.

Comment: `date()` would give you a string of todays date. also the dobs in array are all atrings. when you do the math. you need to convert them to timestamps. you missing that. refer to the above code.

Comment: you are substracting a string from a string. That has to be corrected to 2 timestamps. then you have to convert the result into years. refer to code above. then your code has multiple resturns. the counts has to be added to an associative array and returned after looping though the array.